# Can I play GTA IV TBOGT with a standard GTA IV?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-iv

My episodes of Liberty City on Xbox doesn't load because of a reading error, I was wondering if I could install the Niko Bellic GTA onto my hard drive and play The Ballad Of Gay Tony?  I still have the episodes of liberty city game.

Answer (score 4):

Nope. They are different games altogether.